# Brew says Wine is installed but it fails to run with "command not found" error

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine

I've recently just had a horrendous Mac hard drive issue which required an erase of the hard drive and a restore from an old back up.

Since it's been back, it's not quite been the same. I had Wine installed however `wine my.exe` no longer works. I get a `-bash: wine: command not found` error. I thought it might somehow have become de-installed, but upon trying to reinstall I get: `wine-1.7.19 already installed To install this version, first 'brew unlink wine'`. I've been having lots of permission errors which can't be corrected by disk utility, all of which are "ACL found but not expected" and brew doctor found a whole load of broken symlinks which have since been pruned. All very odd behaviour.

How do I get Wine to run without having to unlink it and reinstall it? I'd much prefer if I could just continue where I left off.

I'm not using MacPorts as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I don't think that `wine` is in your path. Try typing `which wine` in the Terminal. If nothing is outputted, you need to add the directory for `wine` to your path.

Comment: @aglasser Ok, so nothing was outputted, how to I add the directory for wine?

Comment: Do you know where it is installed? You can add a variable to the path by looking at a tutorial like: http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.U9aWY4BdVgw

Comment: Basically, edit `/etc/paths` with `sudo` (if you don't like `nano`, do something like `sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/paths`. Add the directory, then save and exit.

Comment: If you don't know where it is installed, try running this: `sudo find / -name "wine"`. It'll take a while since it's searching the whole hard drive (since I have NO idea where `wine` is installed).

Comment: Sorry, you shouldn't really do this. brew installs things to a particular place and then links them to /usr/local/bin. Manually adding a specific path like this would probably work initially but then cause issues down the road when you wanted to update or run other other brew software.

Comment: Does brew link everything into `/usr/local/bin`? Last I checked, it added things wherever it wanted on the drive (which is a primary reason that I chose MacPorts instead).

Comment: It's relatively clean (to my mind anyway :) ). As I understand it everything gets installed to `/usr/local/Cellar` and then its just the links that exist in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a simple problem then `brew unlink wine` and `brew link wine` might resolve it. This isn't the same as uninstalling and reinstalling, which would be `brew remove wine` and `brew install wine`. It should be quite quick.

When brew installs a piece of software it installs it to `/usr/local/Cellar` and then links it to `/usr/local/bin`. Unlinking just removes those links, so it is still there but basically sitting somewhere it wouldn't normally be found.

But the first thing to try would be to check that `/usr/local/bin` is in your path. You can check this by typing `echo $PATH` in a Terminal window. You should see something like `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: As a MacPorts user, I was guessing in my comments (which is why I didn't post an answer). Hopefully you are of more help than I :)

Comment: Ok done `echo $PATH` and got `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin` which seems about right. I'll let you know how the link/unlink goes

Comment: link/unlink worked. It removed 13 symlinks and added 59! Ace, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/wine